# Difference in Mongo Update<T> and Update

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having a query I'm using to update an embedded array inside another document.
I've tried to different approaches based on the same query to but get two different results

First approach

```
collection.Update(mongoQuery, MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.SetWrapped("Expenses.$.Description", "some text"));
```

Here the Description of the embedded document in the Expenses collection gets updated as expected.

Reading a bit more of the C# API I found the generic Update and tried this:

```
collection.Update(mongoQuery, Update<Expense>.Set(e => e.Description, "some text"));
```

Not the same result. Instead of updating the embedded document, the parent document gets a new property named Description.

I can see on the first query that I'm more explicit about the "Expenses" collection, and in the second I'm just specifying the type Expense. Now is it possible to do the same update in a generic manner?

Comment: Is not that the diff in the names the problem? Expenses in first and Expense in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit similar to the last question you asked, and I think there's some misconception about what LINQ can do and can't do.

The second line contains the expression `Update<Expense>.Set(e => e.Description, "some text")`. It's important to realize that this statement operates 100% context-free: it has absolutely no clue about the fact that is used on an 'embedded object' or that it is, in this case, used in an array query where the positional operator `$` exists.

You expect that `Update<T>.Set(e => e.Prop)` knows that it's called in the context of some query on type `T2`, and that it knows that the only property of type `T` in `T2` is called `Expenses` and that it knows that this is an array and that it must have been matched using an array expression. As you can see, the driver would have to consider quite a bunch of things to do all the magic, even if it's just inserting a `$` and replacing a name in the output.

Let's say you had two arrays of `Expense` in your parent object, `ExpensesA` and `ExpensesB`. How would the driver know, from the second query, that it shall refer to `ExpensesA`, not `ExpensesB`.

As a general rule, if your collection is of type `T`, you want to use only `Query<T>` and `Update<T>` in there, e.g. `db.Update<Event>(Query<Event>.EQ(p=>p.Id, 12), Update<Event>.Set(p => p.Details.Date, newDate))`. If you want to use features that are special to MongoDB, you'll have to use the string-based methods in many cases.